# Modifying a Wine Cooler

Tags: power-supply

new member here with a question.

My Wine Enthusiast Wine Cooler (Model 254 60), bit the dust.  The new boards cost $297 each and there are three in the unit.

I want to remove all of the boards and use a 12 volt power supply on a timer.  The connections would be (3) Peltier's, (3) fans cooling side and (3) fans heating (exhaust side).  All connections wired in series.

What kind of 12 volt power supply would I need to complete the task?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. Otherwise, the question is far too broad. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Comment: This is a bad idea on so many levels. First of all, if they're all 12V devices, you'd wire them in parallel, not series. Using a timer means that you're giving up any pretense of temperature control. As for your actual question about selecting a power supply, that's already been answered many times.

Comment: We can't tell you. You need to calculate the amount of energy which needs to be displaced, from that calculate the type/size of Peltier elements you need, from that the voltage and current they need, add the fan power. Then we can tell you what supply you need. (But by then you may have learned enough to calculate it yourself).

Comment: You are correct with parallel connections.   I did a mini trial, hooked up all red leads to Positive and black leads to Negative on a terminal strip.  Power supply was a Tripp-Lite PR-7b.  The unit started to cool, all fans running.  Temperature settled to 66 F.  I then hooked the led lights to the terminal strip.  Lights worked but the power supply was getting real hot.  That is when I shut things down.